# Give an example of a 2-regular graph with 7 vertices and 2 components

Tags: graph-theory

Could an example of this be a square and a triangle where the two are non connected? As long as it doesn't specify the graph is connected, I'm assuming it's okay to have two separate figures like this?

and to further elaborate, would it be okay to describe all 2-regular graphs with n components as graphs with vertices having a degree of 2 and all components of the graph being cycles?

Comment: It's OK, it's correct and it's the only solution. And yes, 2-regular graphs are either cycles or disjoint unions of cycles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess that your example goes. Consider the set of vertices $\mathcal{V}=\{1,2,3,4,5,6,7\}$ and the set of edges $\mathcal{E}=\{(1,2),(2,3),(3,4),(4,1),(5,6),(6,7),(7,5)\}$.
Another example (if you allow multiple edges between two given vertices): choose the same $\mathcal{V}$ and modify $\mathcal{E}$ as follows:
$$
\mathcal{E}=\{(1,2),(2,3),(3,4),(4,5),(5,1),(6,7),(7,6)\}.
$$
Moreover, if your graph is *finite*, then, to get $n$ components, knowing that the degree of each vertex is $2$, you have to consider $n$ cycles.